# Facebook Graph API Delete permissions

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

Trying to revoke a users access to my facebook application and stuck on this error:

> "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

From what I understand all that is required is to do a HTTP DELETE request to the graph api url

Here is the code I'm using :

```
using ( var client = new System.Net.WebClient() ){
                    client.Headers[ System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType ] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbString + "/permissions?access_token=X";
                    client.UploadString( url, "DELETE", "" );
            }
```

I can't use javascript as I do for the login/signup , this has to happen serverside.

I've seen some posts on a facebook api for C# not sure if that is trustworthy , this code above sounds simpler (with no external dependencies) if it would just work.